# Accessing data within a promise

Tags: angularjs

I wan't to access the data in my controller just after the call to getAllMenuItems function:

```
 x.factory('menuItemsData', function($http, $q){

    return {
    getAllMenuItems: function(){
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/MenuItems.json'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, menuItemsData){
    menuItemsData.getAllMenuItems().success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
   myService.getAllMenuItems().success(function(res){
       // access the response here.
       $scope.menuItems = res.Items; // assign the menuitems.
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from a promise like this:

```
menuItemsData.getAllMenuItems().then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menuItemsData.getAllMenuItems().then(
    function(res){ 
        //success callback
        },
    function(error){ 
        //failure callback
        }
    );
```